# Regularization of heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have seen in Evans book and some papers that they call the equation
\begin{equation}
u_{t}-\Delta u { - \varepsilon u_{tt}}= 0,
\end{equation}
regularization of parabolic equation. Why do we add $\varepsilon u_{tt}$?
Could you please help me with right discussion on this?

Answer (score 1):

If $\varepsilon=0$, the equation in OP amounts to $u_t - \Delta u =0$, which is the classical heat equation deduced from Fourier's law of heat conduction ($u$ is a temperature). According to this model, a temperature perturbation propagates at infinite speed. If $\varepsilon<0$, the equation in OP $u_t - \Delta u-\varepsilon u_{tt} =0$ is the [hyperbolic heat equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_heat_conduction) deduced from the Maxwell-Cattaneo-Vernotte law of heat conduction. This model guarantees that a temperature perturbation propagates at finite speed.